# CSS transition being fired upon load with link and input elements (chrome)

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles using a link and an input element simultaneously, which is pretty odd!

CSS transitions are being fired upon load, even tho I'm using an hover effect and only if the input element is present on the site. All this is for Chrome, haven't tested this in other browsers.

Here is my code simplified to the issue at hand:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Test search" />
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    background: #000;
    transition: background 3s ease;
}

a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Link to example: https://embed.plnkr.co/ri5FknRdbPDY7T2lNldS/ Try and refresh the live preview a couple of times to see the issue. (This will not work on JSFiddle or Codepen, simple because they use internal styles. To reproduce this problem the styling has to come from an external stylesheet which is why I created this on Plunker.)

If I inline the css code in style tags in the head, there is no problem. If I remove the input element, there is no problem either. And it seems only to be a problem on link elements.

What is going on here? :)
- Thanks!

Comment: can you try

transition:all 3s ease !important;

Comment: I'd assume that something must be interfering with it, whether it be elsewhere in your styles, your page, or even plnkr. I couldn't replicate the issue in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6un3pym2/1/

Comment: @Cgdl - didn't help :(

Comment: @Santi - JSFiddle will be inlining the styles, and it's only an issue when it's coming from an external css file

Comment: At this point, I'm just wondering if this is an Chrome bug. This seem to work fine in order browsers.

Comment: This works for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Rob - next time please dont remove the link, just give a heads up regarding the link being down. I added it again. The question still has sufficient code, so any can reproduce the issue - as you can see in the plunker codeview.

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the code that shows the problem here. Third party sites are not allowed cause they may disappear or change tomorrow, helping no one in the future though you may use them in conjunction with what you post here. For that reason, your question may still be removed until you do so.

Comment: @Rob yea, i read the rule. My question still contain all the code for reproducing this issue, even without the 3rd party link. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Then my previous comment still applies. I have no issue with it working in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug, and it has been reported.

A hacky way to fix this is to include a script tag somewhere on the site.

Comment: Can you not supply more details than that?